# showing how numerical solution coming close to the real selution

Tags: matlab, plot, bisection

I want to plot the graph of the numerical solution of bisection method and show how it get close to the real solution . 
my code:

```
% f=input('please enter the function:');
%  xL=input('please enter the limits .from:');
%  XR=input('to:');
% eps=input('please enter epsilon:');
f=@(x)x.^2-1;
XR=2;
xL=-2;
XL=xL ;
eps=0.001;
subplot(2,1,1);
title('graph 1');
    ezplot(f);
    hold on ;
    % line([0 0],40);
    % line(-40,[0 0]);
    plot(XR,f(XR),'r*');
    plot(xL,f(xL),'r*');
    disp( 'the answers is : ');
    for df=xL:0.15:XR
        if f(xL)*f(df)<= 0
        xR=df;
        Roots = BisectionM(f,xR,xL,eps);
        plot(Roots,f(Roots),'gs');
        disp(Roots);
        xL=df;
        xR=XR;
        end
    end
subplot(2,1,2);
title('graph 2');
x0=fzero(f,xL);
sol = BisectionM(f,xR,xL,eps);
plot(1:1:100,ones(1,100)*x0);
hold on ;
plot(1:1:100,sol);
```

the function :

```
function[sol,Roots] = BisectionM(f,xR,xL,eps)
      while abs(xR - xL) > eps
             xM = (xR + xL) / 2;
             if (f(xL))*(f(xM)) > 0
                 xL = xM;
                 sol=xM;
                 plot(xL,f(xL),'.');
             else
                 xR = xM;
                 plot(xR,f(xR),'.');
                  sol=xM;
             end
             Roots = xM;

        end
    end
```

I don't know how to plot this so it will get closer to the solution (the blue line at the end). anyone?

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand many things in your code, e.g. why `BisectionM` has two identical outputs under different variable names (`sol`, `Roots`), moreover only one output is used throughout the main function. Besides here is my guess what you might want:

[image]

The figure shows how the numerical solution converges with respect to iteration number. For this you have to store the iteration results in a vector (`sol`), please see below the modified code:

**main.m**

```
f=@(x)x.^2-1;
XR=2;
xL=-2;
XL=xL ;
eps=0.001;
subplot(2,1,1);
title('graph 1');
ezplot(f);
hold on ;
% line([0 0],40);
% line(-40,[0 0]);
plot(XR,f(XR),'r*');
plot(xL,f(xL),'r*');
disp( 'the answers is : ');
for df=xL:0.15:XR
    if f(xL)*f(df)<= 0
        xR=df;
        Roots = BisectionM(f,xR,xL,eps);
        plot(Roots(end),f(Roots(end)),'gs');
        disp(Roots(end));
        xL=df;
        xR=XR;
    end
end
subplot(2,1,2);
title('graph 2');
% give the wide interval again because it was changed previously
XR=2;
xL=-2;
x0=fzero(f,xL);
Roots = BisectionM(f,xR,xL,eps);
plot(1:length(Roots),ones(length(Roots),1)*x0, 'g');
hold on ;
plot(1:length(Roots),Roots,'Marker', '.');
xlabel('iteration number')
```

**BisectionM.m**

```
function Roots = BisectionM(f,xR,xL,eps)

% no preallocation because of while
ii = 1;
while abs(xR - xL) > eps
    xM = (xR + xL) / 2;
    if (f(xL))*(f(xM)) > 0
        xL = xM;
        sol=xM;
        plot(xL,f(xL),'.');
    else
        xR = xM;
        plot(xR,f(xR),'.');
        sol=xM;
    end
    Roots(ii) = xM;
    ii = ii + 1;
end
end
```

Comment: i wanted to have the root from the function(BisectionM) and to plot how it get close to it on graph 1.
can you explain why you put counter(ii) ?

Comment: I think the second plot shows just what you want, does it? `ii` is required to store the iteration results and because of `while`.